# RewriteRule all except other rewrite already declared

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following entries handled as fixed files using .htaccess (for example)

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^redir$ redir_base64.php
RewriteRule ^confirm$ confirm.php
RewriteRule ^migrate$ migrate.php
RewriteRule ^import_conn$ import_conn.php
RewriteRule ^callback_ot$ callback_ot.php
RewriteRule ^callback_yh$ callback_yh.php
RewriteRule ^callback_gp$ callback_gp.php
RewriteRule ^callback_lk$ callback_lk.php
RewriteRule ^results/map$ index.php
RewriteRule ^results$ index.php
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^removeml$ removeml.php
RewriteRule ^rss$ rss_gen.php
RewriteRule ^cpt\.jpg$ c/captcha/captcha.php
RewriteRule ^cptfrm\.jpg$ c/captcha/captcha.php?width=120&height=60&characters=4
RewriteRule ^cptfrm160\.jpg$ c/captcha/captcha.php?width=100&height=60&characters=3
RewriteRule ^login/lk$ login_conn.php?op=lk
RewriteRule ^t$ c/thumb/phpThumb.php
RewriteRule ^spce$ spce.php
RewriteRule ^orplkd$ order_publisher.php
RewriteRule ^ord_ren$ order_reactivate.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
```

This entry works fine! But I need to access /000/000 and I see that an conflict with lines indicates below.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([\d\w\-\.]+)/([\d]+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\d\w\-\.]+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I try to access to my site using that lines but I cannot to recognize only the last lines because use ALL access on the site.

I hope so understand my help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the 2 conditions. Rewrite conditions **only** apply to the immediately following condition.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\d\w\-\.]+)/([\d]+)$ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\d\w\-\.]+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```